# Is a Cache of type T possible?

Tags: c#, caching

Can we avoid casting `T` to `Object` when placing it in a Cache?

`WeakReference` necessitate the use of objects.  `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache` is locked to type object.

Custom Dictionaries / Collections cause issues with the Garbage Collector, or you have to run a Garbage Collector of your own (a seperate thread)?

Is it possible to have the best of both worlds?

---

I know I accepted an answer already, but using WeakReference is now possible!  Looks like they snuck it into .Net 4.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712911(v=VS.96).aspx

---

an old feature request for the same.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/98270/make-a-generic-form-of-weakreference-weakreference-t-where-t-class

Comment: You want to cache an instance of type T, or the `typeof(T)`?

Comment: I'd like a Cache that uses Generics.  So of type T.  Cache<T>.Get().  Possibly Cache.Cache<T>.Get() would be useful too.  With the ideal that you could still have object access via Cache.Get()

Comment: So you are going to cache `Type t = typeof(T);`, an instance of `Type`,  nothing special.

Comment: Don't think that casting is the problem, as everything is (by definition) an object. Even if you create a custom cashe, and it only caches `BaseClass` instances, what if I want to cashe a `DerivedClass` instance?

Comment: it seems possible to do Caching more efficiently -- conceptually it does at leat.  I'm visualising a paging system for objects... and the casting does seem to get in the way just a little for this usage case.

Comment: perhaps if you could say to C#... this object is of type T, trust me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing to stop you writing a generic wrapper around `MemoryCache` - probably with a constraint to require reference types:

```
public class Cache<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly MemoryCache cache = new MemoryCache();

    public T this[string key]
    {
        get { return (T) cache[key]; }
        set { cache[key] = value; }
    }

    // etc
}
```

Obviously it's only worth delegating the parts of `MemoryCache` you're really interested in.

Comment: that's what I was thinking of doing (btw: I have a test project with this type of code)... but we've got the cast issue here which concerns me.  Not a problem for many solutions I know.  Just concerned if there's a dynamic paging aspect to the object.

Comment: @sgtz: You know the cast will work, because you're the only code which can ever put anything in there. I've no idea what you mean by "dynamic paging aspect".

Comment: agreed.  In this case the objects are fine grained, and reused from a number of places -- dynamic paging wasn't accurate (typed it as I was rushing out the door).  Maybe C is the only place for this kind of thing.  While in C# stick with type safety, and trust the compiler.

Comment: @JonSkeet Why does it require a constraint to reference types? Also do you know any existing implementations of this generic wrapper?

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları: I can't remember why I put the constraint on (although I mentione it at the start), to be honest. I don't know of any similar implementations, I'm afraid.

Comment: @JonSkeet You may have put the constraint to prevent boxing because MemoryCache takes values as object type. Would that be a critical thing for the generic wrapper performance?

Comment: Isn't the class constraint there due to the cast to T, that would not work for a value type? It could be lifted with some sort of default(T) "construction" it there is no hit in the cache

Comment: @Konstantin: No, a cast to `T` would still be fine for a value type - it would just be unboxing.

Answer (score 1):

So you basically want to dependanct inject a cache provider that only returns certain types?
Isn't that kind of against everything OOP?

The idea of the "object" type is that anything and everything is an object so by using a cache that caches instances of "objects" of type object you are saying you can cache anything.

By building a cache that only caches objects of some predetermined type you are limiting the functionality of your cache however ...

There is nothing stopping you implementing a custom cache provider that has a generic constraint so it only allows you cache certain object types, and this in theory would save you about 2 "ticks" (not even a millisecond) per retrieval.

The way to look at this is ...

What's more important to me:

1. Good OOP based on best practise
2. about 20 milliseconds over the lifetime of my cache provider

The other thing is ... .net is already geared to optimise the boxing and unboxing process to the extreme and at the end of the day when you "cache" something you are simply putting it somewhere it can be quickly retrieved and storing a pointer to its location for that retrieval later.

I've seen solutions that involve streaming 4GB XML files through a business process that use objects that are destroyed and recreated on every call .. the point is that the process flow was important not so much the initialisation and prep work if that makes sense.

How important is this casting time loss to you?
I would be interested to know more about scenario that requires such speed.

As a side note:
Another thing i've noticed about newer technologies like linq and entity framework is that the result of query is something that is important to cache when the query takes a long time but not so much the side effects on the result.

What this means is that (for example):
If i was to cache a basic "default instance" of an object that uses a complex set of entity queries to create, I wouldn't cache the resulting object but the queries.

With microsoft already doing the ground work i'd ask ... what am i caching and why?

Comment: I think it's entirely reasonable to want a `Cache<T>` - not for *performance* reasons, but for *type safety* reasons. If I know the only objects I want to put in the cache are of a particular type, why would I want to have the casts everywhere I fetch the values, and the possibility of accidentally putting in the wrong kind of value? I see nothing in that idea that goes "against everything OOP". Do you object to `List<T>` on those grounds too?

Comment: "dependanct inject a cache provider that only returns certain types".  I started thinking about this after considering the way nhibernate uses Castle Windsor to create a proxy, which was followed by "this is overkill for me, but I want some of that with a twist.  I'll stick with type safety for now.  Also, was reaching at this from a functional programming perspective.  So objects are little bit more fine grained + the casting cost is increased.  Oh well.

Comment: sgtz: The entire microsoft provider model is basically a structural mechanism for dependancy injections (as i understand it) so using any form of provider that inherits from ProviderBase is basically a wrapped up dependancy injection.

Comment: Jon: sorry if i was bit literal ... but the point i was getting at is that the cost of boxing + unboxing / casting is so low that it won't make a difference in real world apps these days but you're willing to limit making a more portable model because of this cost? i'm a little confused by it.

Comment: I'm thinking about this in my head being akin to "i want a database but i only want to store strings in it so i'm going to define a table that only has string column types", what happens if you want to store integers dates, booleans, those columns are in fact less efficient in the grand scheme of things ... with your model you would then likely have a second, thirds, and N'th cache for other object types ... then you would have to write a cache manager to manage all your caches and so on ... of course i'm assuming that your app will eventually do what everyone elses apps do and grow over time

Comment: I don't see how having Cache<T> would be less efficient in any way unless you specify how. I don't see why you would need any kind of manager either. What is it about having a Cache<int>, a Cache<string>, etc. that requires a CacheManager to deal with them? If you mean the ability to group caches then just make an abstract Cache base-class and throw them into an array or other collection of choice. I'm saying you're not backing up your opinions with anything concrete like examples, usage scenarios or facts. Only fact presented is that boxing is negligibly slower.